# Display busy progressBar for long process, no thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, progress-bar

I'm writing a PyQt GUI application, and I would like to display a busy progress bar for one of my function, which takes time to finish. Here is the code:

```
self.progress = QtGui.QProgressDialog("Canceling...", None, 0, 0, self)
self.progress.setWindowTitle("Canceling refresh")
self.progress.show()

timer = QtCore.QTimer()
timer.singleShot(0, self.loadNotifications)

while timer.isActive():
    app.processEvents()
```

For now, I tried something with a QTimer, but it doesn't work. The CPU-bound function is `loadNotifications`.

I would like to start it in a sort of a thread, and while it's running, update the QProgressBar.

I could of course create a QThread class around the function loadNotifications, but it's a bit overkill for what I want to do: simply display a smooth progressBar while the function is running.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You can either update the progress bar in the function that you are running which will freeze your application or (as you already mentioned) you spawn a new thread for the execution of the function which is a common way to handle this kind of things. You can use `connect` to update the progress bar.

Comment: Isn't there a flexible way to spawn a thread with just the long function as a parameter ?

Comment: You can write your own small class for that purpose. Take a look at https://joplaete.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/threading-with-pyqt4/.

Comment: Yes, very elegant and flexible. I'll use that. But why can't we do that by default ?

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience with PyQT, but in tkinter, I usually accomplish this by making my slow function periodically call some `update_progbar` function passed to it. This `update_progbar` function then updates the progress bar in the same thread as the slow function (which is therefore temporarily on hold).

Rudimentary:

```
def update_progbar(prog):
    print(prog)

def slow_function(prog_func):
    for i in range(100000):
        if i%1000 == 0:
           prog_func(i / 100000.0)
        do_something()
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, and @a_guest mentioned it too. The thing is it's not very flexible, you have to add some function calls in the slow function. In my case, I just would have to call ```app.processEvents()``` regularly.

Comment: Your function is going to have to do something anyway. How else would your GUI even know what the current progress is?

Comment: I don't have to know what the progress is actually, I just need a busy progress bar (so I set the values of the progressBar to (0, 0)).